# Can I temporarily suspend SharePoint Server + IIS + SQL Server?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7, suspend, taskmanager

Is there a way to temporarily suspend / pause Sharepoint Server 2010, IIS and SQL Server services without killing them in Task Manager? I am not running VM or Hyper-V, so most of my resources are constantly used by those 3 major server applications.

It's just I am not always in SharePoint 2010. Ocasionally I'd like to play StarCraft 2 or work in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this nice little utility in Codeplex to start/stop all services of SharePoint 2010.

[SharePoint 2010 Service Manager](http://sharepointserviceman.codeplex.com/)

Comment: ;-) I use this at home in my laptop. Just blogged about it today http://www.allaboutmoss.com/index.php/2010/08/11/sharepoint-2010-service-manager/

Answer (score 2):

You could write a script to stop and start the required services like this and place it in a .bat file:

net start service

net stop service

Just choose all the service names you need to start and stop and create two bat files one to stop and one to start

Comment: That could work too but as Shoban has suggested there's a better solution for that - SharePoint 2010 Service Manager - from CodePlex.